# Solr Start Error

Tags: windows, solr

I am trying to install Solr on Windows 7 running Apache server.  I navigate to the installation folder solr-5.4.0 and run bin/solr start.  But I keep getting the following error:

```
This script requires extracting a WAR file with either the jar or unzip utility, please install these utilities or contact your administrator for assistance.
```

Here is my Java version:

```
$ java -version 
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode)
```

I have also set the JAVA_HOME variable.

I think Java should be extracting the WAR file.  I've found several technical discussions related to this on apache site, such as [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7227), but can't find any clear resolution.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  If the answer involves installing a patch, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows you should be using `solr.cmd` per the [Solr reference guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr).

```
bin\solr.cmd start
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows run

> **`solr.cmd start`**

from bin directory and follow the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/solr-tutorial.html#launch-solr-in-solrcloud-mode) .

If you want to run interactive tutorial use command:

> **solr start -e cloud**